# Interactive bash script for two selections: folder and subfolder

Tags: bash

I would like to create a simple interactive selection bash script, which should show a list of directories of a specific folder and depending on the first selection it should do a second selection in this folder. With these two selections, the script will do some specific things.

This is how the starting script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

title="Project"
prompt="Select project"
options=("A", "B") # How to use subfolders of a specific folder?

echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do
    case "$REPLY" in
    1) echo "$opt";; # do something specific to this value
    2) echo "$opt";; # do something specific to this value
    $((${#options[@]}+1))) echo "Goodbye."; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option."; continue;;
    esac
done
```

Instead of hardcoding options I would like to use this result:

```
for d in apps/*/ ; do basename "$d" ; done
```

How do I get this result as `options` value?

And after selections, it should do the same thing for this selected folder:

```
for d in apps/$opt/*/ ; do basename "$d" ; done
```

Depending on this selection there should be done different things / commands / calculations.

**Summary**

User should select a subfolder of a specific directory (=app) and then select again a subfolder (=project). With this I do have two values (app and project) for further calculations.

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit. Updating your question is fine, but changing it so that the answer(s) you received is problematic. Perhaps (accept the answer you received and) ask a new question if you now have a new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard will get expanded in any context.

```
options=( */ )
```

Depending on your users' (lack of) sophistication, you might want to postprocess the result; this will populate the array with `A/ B/` where the trailing slash is important for selecting only directories.

(In many situations, the variable is an unnecessary and slightly wasteful indirection; if you don't care about postprocessing, you can simply say

```
select opt in */ "Quit"
```

directly. Depending on your use case, you might want or need to add a prefix `./` too, to disambiguate any directories which start with a minus sign.)

To explicitly run `basename` on each entry, maybe use a loop to populate the array:

```
# local n
options=( )
for n in ./*/; do
    options+=("$(basename "$n")")
done
```

Often, you want to avoid external processes when you can; a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) will be slightly clunkier, but much more efficient.

Concentrating on just the `select` problem, I guess you are looking for something like

```
select opt in */ "Quit"
do
    case "$REPLY" in
        "Quit") break;;
    esac
    select final in "app/$opt"/* "Quit"
    do
        case "$REPLY" in
            "Quit") break;;
        esac
        echo "You chose $REPLY"
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I handle the second selection, which uses the previous selected folder?

Comment: `select final in "apps/$opt/"*`

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my comment. As far as I understand that, I have to use two nested select commands. Both are using different options - the second one depends on the first selection. So my problem is how to do the second selection, which of course uses `"apps/$opt/"*`. I've updated the code in my post. Could you please post a code example?

Comment: I really do fail to see how doing it again would be different from doing it once; but I updated with a code snippet.